# Android Direct Share : Find application associated to a contact

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio, android-contacts, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm currently trying to implement the Direct Share introduced in Android 6.0.

example

[image]

So what I'm doing is retrieving contacts whose LAST_TIME_CONTACTED value is the highest. Now that I have those contacts (and more specifically their CONTACT_ID), how can I determine which app was used resulting in LAST_TIME_CONTACTED being updated ?

Unless I've missed something, when creating my ChooserTargets for each contact I want to be directly contacted, I need to provide a ComponentName, but I'm missing both the application package name and activity entry point.

Thank you in advance for your help !